# Unable to respond to HEAD requests in Java

Tags: java, http-headers

I am writing a personal web server.
When I send the GET request to the system, the system responds well.
But when I send the HEAD request, I get the following problems:

> sun.net.httpserver.ExchangeImpl sendResponseHeaders
> WARNING: sendResponseHeaders: being invoked with a content length for a HEAD
> request java.io.IOException: response headers not sent yet    at
> jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.PlaceholderOutputStream.checkWrap(ExchangeImpl.java:448)
> at
> jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.PlaceholderOutputStream.write(ExchangeImpl.java:458)
> at
> ir.utux.service.HandleHttpResponse.writeResponse(HandleHttpResponse.java:32)

This is the code I wrote to manage the response, to simplify HEAD and GET together.

```java
public void writeResponse(SettingModal settingModal) {
    try {
        switch (requestHeader.getMethod()) {
            case HEAD,GET -> {
                response.getResponseHeaders().set("Server", "utux HttpServer");
                response.getResponseHeaders().set("Connection", "close");
                response.getResponseHeaders().set("Transfer-encoding", "chunked");
                response.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", ContentType.HTML);
                response.sendResponseHeaders(HttpStatus.SC_OK, "".length());
                response.getResponseBody().write("".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                response.getResponseBody().flush();
                response.getResponseBody().close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem
BODY should not be sent in response to HEAD requests.